# Submit Data from a HTML form to a Database in Django

Tags: django, database, forms

What I'm trying to do is to allow a user to enter any text in a form and have the data stored in a database. However, it is not being saved when I test it. I'm sure it's probably something stupid, but any help will be appreciated. I'm also pretty new to using Django.

Below is what I have currently have. Any help will be appreciated.

models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

class TEST(models.Model):
    test_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class Test_Form(forms.Form):
    test_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from Test.forms import Test_Form
from Test.models import Test
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'Test/Test.html')

def Test_View(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = Test_Form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
                test_name = request.POST.get('test_name', '')

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('Test:IOC'))

    else:
        form = Test_Form()

    return render(request, 'Test/Test.html', {'form': form})
```

Snippet from test.html

```
<form action="/Test/" method="POST" id="Test" class="form-horizontal form-groups-bordered"     role="form">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group">

<div class="row">
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="test_title">Full Name of Test</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <input id="ioc_name" class="form-control" name="test_name" type="CharField" data-validate="required" placeholder="ex: This is a test">
</div>

<div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-9">
    <a class="btn btn-success btn-icon">
    Submit
        <input type="submit" />
        <i class="entypo-check"></i>
    </a>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why do you think this code should save anything? Where are you doing anything to cause data to be saved?

Answer (score 1):

The model instance isn't save automatically with magic. You need to instantiate it, assign the data, and call the save method, like this:

```
test = TEST(test_name=form.cleaned_data["test_name"])
test.save()
```

Or in one step: `TEST.create(test_name=form.cleaned_data["test_name"])`

Or even shorter (if I remember well): `TEST.create(**form.cleaned_data)`

You should check the docs from creating forms from models, it'll get your work easier (this is for Django 1.1.0) (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Also, your `input` is wrong:

1. You have to set `type` to a valid value (`text` in this case). Anyway, as t doesn't recognizes `CharField` as a valid type, it sets its value to `text`, which is the default, so you don't have problems here. [Valid types](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp)
2. I don't know if `data-validate` is part of your own code, but if not and you wanna the field be required before hitting submit, you should use [required](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp), which is an HTML attr.